# How to get position for fixed element without jquery?

Tags: javascript, position, fixed

**Hello there**

I have an element with fixed position, I can't detect position and must be use javascript clearly, without frameworks (jquery, mootools, etc).

Comment: Possible Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/dynamically-retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function findPos(obj) {

    var curleft = curtop = 0;

    if (obj.offsetParent)
    do {
        curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
        curtop += obj.offsetTop;

    } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);

    return [curleft,curtop];
}
```

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html

Comment: You have a syntax problem first of all, you open the "{" (look at "if (obj.offsetParent) {" ) but you don't close it!  Anyway this doesn't work for scrolled divs.

Answer (score 11):

Use:

```
var boundingBox = node.getBoundingClientRect();
```

Check out the result, you have an object like this:

```
top    : 0,
right  : 0,
bottom : 0,
left   : 0,
width  : 0,
height : 0
```

Answer (score 5):

Does this help:

```
document.getElementById('id').offsetLeft // + window.scrollX
document.getElementById('id').offsetTop // + window.scrollY
```

You might want to look at : **[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/dynamically-retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element)**

Comment: If you want to get the same result as what jQuery gives, you need to minus margin.

Answer (score 0):

For a cross platform solution, you might want to look at the the micro-framework [`Popper.js`](https://popper.js.org/) source. I found your question by trying to resolve this popper problem, but I believe it is applicable to any fixed element.